# HOWTO: beautifulsoup4 delete content and tags through find or the find_all

Tags: beautifulsoup

I come through the matter,while i found out the tags and contets via the find,the problem is how to delete it,here is my example:

```
html="""<a href="http://digi.tech.com/a/20160621/050783.htm" rel="nofollow" <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="atd"><tbody><tr><td id="article_content"><p align="center" class="pageLink">
</p>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img alt=" " data-bd-imgshare-binded="1" height="220" src="/skin/vr186/images/wxin.jpg" width="220"/></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(102, 204, 204);"><strong>every day 5</strong></span></p>
<div id="click_div"><div class="left_boxs_tit4"><div class="blank10"></div>
<a name="pl"></a>
<div class="blank20"></div><div class="feelings"><iframe frameborder="0" height="200" id="mood_frame" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="/e/extend/mood/?classid=2&amp;id=4559" width="538"></iframe></div></div></div>"""
```

I now can use the following get the contents and tags above

```
a = beautifulsoup(html)
fst =  a.find(class_="atd")
next_siblings = fst.find_next_siblings()
```

to get the strings below:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="atd"><tbody><tr><td id="article_content"><p align="center" class="pageLink">
</p>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img alt=" " data-bd-imgshare-binded="1" height="220" src="/skin/vr186/images/wxin.jpg" width="220"/></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(102, 204, 204);"><strong>every day 5</strong></span></p>
<div id="click_div"><div class="left_boxs_tit4"><div class="blank10"></div>
<a name="pl"></a>
<div class="blank20"></div><div class="feelings"><iframe frameborder="0" height="200" id="mood_frame" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="/e/extend/mood/?classid=2&amp;id=4559" width="538"></iframe></div></div>
```

**but** , i can't delete it via the del a['tag_name'] , because it is one small part of a long article,  how to delete the tag and its contents by its id ???

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select the element and *extract* it:

```
html="""<a href="http://digi.tech.com/a/20160621/050783.htm" rel="nofollow" <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="atd"><tbody><tr><td id="article_content"><p align="center" class="pageLink">
</p>
</td></tr></tbody></table>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img alt=" " data-bd-imgshare-binded="1" height="220" src="/skin/vr186/images/wxin.jpg" width="220"/></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(102, 204, 204);"><strong>every day 5</strong></span></p>
<div id="click_div"><div class="left_boxs_tit4"><div class="blank10"></div>
<a name="pl"></a>
<div class="blank20"></div><div class="feelings"><iframe frameborder="0" height="200" id="mood_frame" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="no" src="/e/extend/mood/?classid=2&amp;id=4559" width="538"></iframe></div></div></div>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

fst =  soup.find(class_="atd")

fst.select_one("#click_div").extract()
print(fst)
```

Which will give you:

```
<a cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="atd" href="http://digi.tech.com/a/20160621/050783.htm" rel="nofollow"><tbody><tr><td id="article_content"><p align="center" class="pageLink">
</p>
</td></tr></tbody>
<p style="text-align: center;"><img alt=" " data-bd-imgshare-binded="1" height="220" src="/skin/vr186/images/wxin.jpg" width="220"/></p>
<p style="text-align: center;"><span style="color: rgb(102, 204, 204);"><strong>every day 5</strong></span></p>
</a>
```

You can use `fst.find(id="click_div").extract()`if you prefer, the outcome will be the same.